# how to create selectable popup panel in gwt

Tags: gwt

I need to create a popup panel in gwt that has selection functionality 
for example : **the suggestion popup that appears when @ is typed in facebook's create post box** . Is it possible to create such a component in gwt .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You could use the [GWT SuggestBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html). For example:

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
oracle.add("A");
oracle.add("B");
oracle.add("C");
oracle.add("D");

SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
```

Another possibility would be a framework like Bootstrap. There is also a [SuggestBox in GwtBootstrap 3](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#suggestBox) (see the Demo). As you can see the usage in the Java code is really similiar. Of course you can place this SuggestBox whereever you like - also in a PopupPanel/Modal.

For a more "Facebook like" example I once saw [this tutorial](https://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete). It's a bit older but perhaps it helps.

Comment: Yes i have tried SuggestBox but it has a input element in it , my requirement is bit different i am showing a popup form which i need to select things whenever @ is pressed in a editable div (exactly similar to facebook's create post box )

Comment: I added you a tutorial for this case. Hopefully this helps. By the way the display of the suggestions can be modified with the SuggestionDisplay.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial it really helped ... also could you suggest any ideas how can i achieve this with gwt https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B05dZwdH6MfnMEV6ejJUaUNTSFk

Comment: No google drive available here. Could you upload somewhere else?

Comment: I have changed the access permission you should be able to open it now .